# What does Android Virtual Device emulator SD Card field do?

Tags: android-emulator

I cannot find anywhere the criteria I should use to choose a value for the Android Virtual Device Emulator SD Card field; e.g., why did someone choose 1024 MiB and someone else choose 688 MiB?

Answer (score 1):

The emulator allows you to create virtual SD cards of different capacities.

Someone wanted to use a 1024MB SD card and the other wanted a 688MB.